# cross domain log in with ajax yql

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, frames, yql

I'm trying to build a webapp to analyze some data in the informatic system of my university (nothing illegal!).

The problem is that they use some pretty old technology and i'm having some difficulties interfacing with their system.

Their login system is based upon sessions stored in cookies and once you entered they fake a one window environment using frames.

I tried to login using yql with password and user name and it works but then i have two problems:

1. How do I retain and send the cookie with the sessionID through yql?
2. How do i access other frames?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No cues?? I really need help with this!